# Destructured vs non-destructured value in React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a simple context example code.

When you run this code and press 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' button respectively. You will only see, ***'Getter is rendered'*** in console.log which is what I want.

**<Example Code: 1>**

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';
import { Button, Text } from 'react-native';

const SetterContext = createContext<any>( () => undefined);
const GetterContext = createContext<boolean>(false);

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider>
            <>
                <Getter />
                <Setter />
            </>
        </Provider>
    );
};

const Provider = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
    const [isFoo, setIsFoo] = useState(false);
    return (
        <GetterContext.Provider value={ isFoo }>
            <SetterContext.Provider value={ setIsFoo }>
                {children}
            </SetterContext.Provider>
        </GetterContext.Provider>
    );
};

const Getter = () => {
    console.log('Getter is rendered');
    const getter = useContext(GetterContext);
    return (
        <Text>{getter ? "TRUE":"FALSE"}</Text>
    )
}

const Setter = () => {
    const setIsFoo = useContext(SetterContext);
    console.log('Setter is rendered')
    return (
        <>
            <Button title="True" onPress={ () => {setIsFoo(true)}}></Button>
            <Button title="False" onPress={ () => {setIsFoo(false)}}></Button>
        </>
    )
}

export default App;
```

However, (see below code),
When I call a setter function in a destructive way, now I see both console.log is printed which means both components are rendered at this time.

It prints both, ***'Getter is rendered'*** and ***'Setter is rendered'*** when the state is changed

**<Example Code: 2>**

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';
import { Button, Text } from 'react-native';

const SetterContext = createContext<any>( () => undefined);
const GetterContext = createContext<boolean>(false);

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider>
            <>
                <Getter />
                <Setter />
            </>
        </Provider>
    );
};

const Provider = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
    const [isFoo, setIsFoo] = useState(false);
    return (
        <GetterContext.Provider value={ isFoo }>
            <SetterContext.Provider value={{ setIsFoo }}>
                {children}
            </SetterContext.Provider>
        </GetterContext.Provider>
    );
};

const Getter = () => {
    console.log('Getter is rendered');
    const getter = useContext(GetterContext);
    return (
        <Text>{getter ? "TRUE":"FALSE"}</Text>
    )
}

const Setter = () => {
    const { setIsFoo } = useContext(SetterContext);
    console.log('Setter is rendered')
    return (
        <>
            <Button title="True" onPress={ () => {setIsFoo(true)}}></Button>
            <Button title="False" onPress={ () => {setIsFoo(false)}}></Button>
        </>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Both example codes are almost the same, the only difference is described below.

**<Example Code in Summary: 1>**

This example prints only, 'Getter is rendered' when the state is changed.

```
// Set directly
<SetterContext.Provider value={ setIsFoo }>

// Call directly
const setter = useContext(SetterContext);
```

**<Example Code in Summary: 2>**

This example prints both, 'Getter is rendered' and 'Setter is rendered' when the state is changed.

```
// Set in Destructive
<SetterContext.Provider value={{ setIsFoo }}>

// Call in Destructive
const { setIsFoo } = useContext(SetterContext);
```

Can you explain why it re-renders both components when 'setIsFoo' is called in a destructive way?

I want to make it render the getter component only when the state is changed.

Comment: In the second example you're creating an object inside the `value` prop — on each render this is a *new* object reference and so forces a  render in Setter. In the first you are passing the setter directly which React guarantees to be the same reference on each render.

Comment: @pilchard Oh I see, Thank you for your comment! (I am just trying to prevent unnecessary renders. Manage state in React is way too complicated than it should be IMO...)

Comment: If you need to pass an object as value you can memoize it before hand.

Comment: @pilchard I think I need to see useMemo hook. cuz I am trying to pass multiple values. Thank you!